# R Shiny: Clicking button in tab hides button/questions/radio buttons and displays results in the same tab instead

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, show-hide, shinyjs

I have a tab with n questions, each associated with Likert style radio buttons. I would like to display the selected answers in a number of different ways (plots etc.) without switching to or creating additional tabs. Instead, I would like to display the results in the same tab that I used for the questions/radio buttons i.e. pressing the button hides the questions, radio buttons and the submit button and displays, for example, a plot or a table with the results.

I created a MWE that illustrates my approach so far. Since I don't know how to best approach this I created three different tabs called `Questions`, `Results` and `Hide` with the intention to hide the `Results` tab until the submit button is clicked which will display the `Results` tab and hide the `Questions` tab. I haven't found a way to hide the `Questions` tab which is why I created the `Hide` tab as a test.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    navbarPage(
        "Hide questions/buttons and display results in same tab",
        id = "navbar",
        tabPanel(title = "Questions",
                 id = "questions",
                 h1("Example questions"),
                 uiOutput("myradios"),
                 actionButton("button", "Run analysis")
        ),
        tabPanel(
            title = "Results",
            value = "results",
            tableOutput("tableOutput"),
            h1("Here are the results"),
            textOutput("txt")
        ),
        tabPanel(
            title = "Hide",
            value = "hide",
            h1("This tab will be hidden when the button in 'Questions' tab is clicked")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
        hide(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=results]")
        show(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=hide]")
    })
    
    output$tableOutput <- renderTable({
        if(input$button > 0){
            toggle(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=results]")
            toggle(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=hide]")
        }else{
            NULL
        }
    })
    outputOptions(output, "tableOutput", suspendWhenHidden=F)
    
    nameList <- c("Q1", "Q2")
    questionList <- c("This is question 1", "This is question 2")
    
    all_radios <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(nameList)) {
        all_radios[[i]] <- p(radioButtons(nameList[i], questionList[i], c("Disagree strongly" = "1", "Disagree a little" = "2","Neutral; no opinion" = "3","Agree a little" = "4","Agree strongly" = "5"), inline=T, selected=0))
    }
    
    output$myradios <- renderUI(all_radios)
    
    output$txt <- renderText({
        return(paste("The answers are:", input$Q1, "and", input$Q2, sep=" "))
    })
    
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

A lot is wrong with this code besides the obvious described above. Clicking the submit button again hides the 'Results' tab again for example.

I would be very grateful for any kind of help or pointer.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @YBS' answer, this is the working solution which also hides the button after clicking it:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    navbarPage(
        "Hide questions/buttons and display results in same tab",
        id = "navbar",
        tabPanel(title = "Questions",
                 id = "questions",
                 h1("Example questions"),
                 uiOutput("myradios"),
                 textOutput("txt"),
                 actionButton("button", "Run analysis")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
        
    nameList <- c("Q1", "Q2")
    questionList <- c("This is question 1", "This is question 2")
    
    all_radios <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(nameList)) {
        all_radios[[i]] <- p(radioButtons(nameList[i], questionList[i], c("Disagree strongly" = "1",
                                                                          "Disagree a little" = "2",
                                                                          "Neutral; no opinion" = "3",
                                                                          "Agree a little" = "4",
                                                                          "Agree strongly" = "5"),
                                          inline=T,
                                          selected=0))
    }
    
    output$myradios <- renderUI(all_radios)
    
    output$txt <- renderText({
        return(paste("The answers are:", input$Q1, "and", input$Q2, sep=" "))
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
        k <- input$button %% 2
        if (k==1) {
            hide("myradios")
            show("txt")
            hide("button")
        }else {
            show("myradios")
            hide("txt")
        }
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- tagList(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(
    "Hide questions/buttons and display results in same tab",
    id = "navbar",
    tabPanel(title = "Questions",
             id = "questions",
             h1("Example questions"),
             uiOutput("myradios"),
             textOutput("txt"),
             actionButton("button", "Run analysis")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      title = "Results",
      value = "results",
      tableOutput("tableOutput"),
      h1("Here are the results"),
      textOutput("txt1")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      title = "Hide",
      value = "hide",
      h1("This tab will be hidden when the button in 'Questions' tab is clicked")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    hide(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=results]")
    show(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=hide]")
  })
  
  output$tableOutput <- renderTable({
    if(input$button > 0){
      toggle(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=results]")
      toggle(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=hide]")
    }else{
      NULL
    }
  })
  outputOptions(output, "tableOutput", suspendWhenHidden=F)
  
  nameList <- c("Q1", "Q2")
  questionList <- c("This is question 1", "This is question 2")
  
  all_radios <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(nameList)) {
    all_radios[[i]] <- p(radioButtons(nameList[i], questionList[i], c("Disagree strongly" = "1", "Disagree a little" = "2","Neutral; no opinion" = "3","Agree a little" = "4","Agree strongly" = "5"), inline=T, selected=0))
  }
  
  output$myradios <- renderUI(all_radios)
  
  output$txt <- renderText({
    return(paste("The answers are:", input$Q1, "and", input$Q2, sep=" "))
  })
  output$txt1 <- renderText({
    return(paste("The answers are:", input$Q1, "and", input$Q2, sep=" "))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    k <- input$button %% 2
    #print(k)
    if (k==1) {
      hide("myradios")
      show("txt")
    }else {
      show("myradios")
      hide("txt")
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @YBS - that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks to your code example I finally understood how hide and show are used in Shinyjs. The next step will be to disable the button until all radiobuttons are selected. I'll update my original question with your code as well. Thanks again and also for your quick reply.